# TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED error when trying to swap BCLNC tokens for ETH on Uniswap

Tags: uniswap, transferfrom

I'm attempting to swap BCLNC tokens for ETH on Uniswap, but I get the following error:

> The transaction cannot succeed due to error: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED. This is probably an issue with one of the tokens you are swapping.

However, it is clear that other transactions are successful such as [this one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0e6ac6a4165f849902da3e2d02607341e985ad00b4546fc80759b907b03264ef/).

I've attempted to perform a `swapExactTokensForETH` directly on the [Uniswap contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#writeContract) replicating the details such as `Path` and the correct values for `amountIn`, `to` and `deadline`, but it attempts to charge me an excessive gas fee (over $160), and MetaMask displays the following error:

> ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.

Any idea what the issue could be here?

Comment: This error is usually the result of you not calling `approve` prior to calling `transferFrom`.

Comment: In other words:

Comment: On the ERC20 contract at address `path[0]`

Comment: You need to execute function `approve(uniswapContractAddress, amountIn)`

Comment: Using the same account which you are trying to execute function `swapExactTokensForETH ` with.

Comment: @goodvibration I did call `approve` as you can see [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb9739f03a776e70cd82a6e32c4ef3f70f08de6da365700430a77f057ceee82a2). The error kept occurring afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, you should approve an amount equal to or larger than the first value in the array returned from `UniswapV2Library.getAmountsOut(factory, amountIn, path)`, so you might wanna check what this function returns on your input.

Comment: @goodvibration You can see from the decoded input data of my `approve` [tx](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb9739f03a776e70cd82a6e32c4ef3f70f08de6da365700430a77f057ceee82a2) that I set the amount to the largest possible `uint256` value (115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935). So any possible value of `getAmountsOut` would work. At the time, Uniswap reported an output of around 2 ETH. Now it's even less. So, this can't be the issue.

Comment: @Neo I'm really sorry to inform you that you were a victim of a [honeypot contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa77ecdec904751a594ff17fc99cb65bebfabe441#code). Look at the ensure modifier, only the owner can make arbitrary transfers.

Comment: @Ismael I can see that `owner` is set in the `constructor` as `msg.sender`, and is also used in the `approval` and `allowance` functions. I don't see how this limits swaps conducted on Uniswap to be limited to a specific address. There's no wallet address specified anywhere in the contract code.

Comment: @Neo Look at `transfer` and `transferFrom` both are guarded by `ensure` modifier. That modifier prevents arbitrary transfers, you can buy tokens from the owner, and from uniswap's pool, but you can't sell them to anyone but the owner.

Comment: @Ismael I can see that `transferFrom` is protected by `ensure`. `owner` is set by `constructor`. I can see from [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#constructor) that `constructor` is executed only when the SC is created. Therefore, this is when `owner` is set in this case, and would be the same address that created the SC. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Neo You are correct. Another suspicious function is `delegate` that allows owner arbitrary code execution.

Comment: Did you get to resolved this? I am having the same error for myself- The transaction cannot succeed due to error: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED. This is probably an issue with one of the tokens you are swapping.

Comment: In my case I had to approve just before calling `swapExactTokensForTokens` 
Example```await TokenA .connect(address1).approve(RouterAddress, amount)```

Answer (score -1):

It is because your function needs to be `payable` if your receiver address is a contract

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but the question is not to transfer Ether. It is to transfer a Token. and it does not need to have wallet payable.

Comment: ah maybe you need to approve your tokens in order for unsiwap to spend it? Dunno if your tokens are an ERC20 token